# Transparent DTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, dtcoretext

Using [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText), `DTAttributedLabel`s always have a white background. Changing the `backgroundColor` doesn't do anything. Setting a background color with CSS shows up, but setting it to clear shows the white background.

Comment: Does it have a different view in the view hierarchy that is not getting updated with your background setting change?

Comment: No. Changing it out for a plain UIView works fine.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  The DTAttributed label may have it's own internal view hierarchy.  Something like (Main View -> Blank view -> -> Text shadow ->Text view -> etc...).  The internal structure could be blocking the overall background from being visible, so you don't see the background at all, just the internal views.  I don't know, I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me to set background color for "DTAttributedLabel" by using "DTCoreText Library".

```
 NSString *html = @"<p>Some Text</p>";
 CGRect frame = self.lblText.frame; // self.lblText is a label from storyboard view controller
 DTAttributedLabel *attLbl = [[DTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    attLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 NSDictionary *options = @{
                                     DTDefaultFontFamily: @"Avenir Next Heavy",
                                     DTDefaultFontSize: @36.0,
                                     NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption: @1.05,
                                     DTDefaultTextColor: [UIColor redColor],
                                     DTDefaultTextAlignment: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTRightTextAlignment]
                                     };

 NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:data options:options documentAttributes:NULL];

 attLbl.attributedString = string;
 [self.view addSubview: attLbl];
```